# Html Checkbox won't check (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Please can someone tell me how to make my checkboxes work, generated with the following JQuery code:

```
var html = '<table width="100%"><tr><th>Include?</th><th>Product ID</th> <th>Product Name</th><th>Detail</th><tr>';

/* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

$.each(productsArray, function (key, value) {

    console.log(key, value);
    html += `<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="product-id" value="${key}"></td><td>${key}</td><td>${value}</td><td></td></tr>`;
});
html += '</table>';
$("#chart-container").html(html);
```

I've tried adding

`onClick="this.checked=!this.checked;"`

as suggested on SO, but that made no difference.

Comment: you don't need to do any onclick until you want to handle that change event, by default rendering <input type="checkbox"> anyhow make the checkbox clickable and checkable by browser, that's default behaviour until you have written some other click event and that prevent the action.

Comment: They're checkable here - http://jsbin.com/hupixuquha/edit?html,js,output

Comment: OOPs, I have `pointer-events:none!important;` in my CSS. My bad!

Comment: you can close your question if it is answered, or not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else makes the same mistake - the cause in this case was in the css: 
`pointer-events:none!important;`